# Are ChatGPT answers allowed here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I know that [ChatGPT is banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Lately, I saw an increase of answers by  ChatGPT .

1. [Join twice on same table with different conditions and no PK / FK relations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322823/join-twice-on-same-table-with-different-conditions-and-no-pk-fk-relations)

   [image: original answer]
2. [Get table data not in pivot table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322746/get-table-data-not-in-pivot-table/322753#322753)

   [image: original answer]

Are the answers generated by ChatGPT banned/allowed on Database Administrators ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Generated answers should NOT be allowed here

There are issues with generated answers, many discussed in the question's link and on [general meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide), where the staff answer says:

> Because sites are impacted to such different degrees by the usage of ChatGPT, we encourage sites to create these policies **as they become an issue**.

If people consult a tool like GPT, learn something, and verify it to be true and accurate to the best of their ability, they can write a normal answer *in their own words*.

Please custom flag obviously generated answers for moderator attention, explaining your reasoning, and we will take the appropriate action. In most cases, this will involve deleting the submitted content and inviting the author to write an original answer based on their own knowledge and experience.

Comment: *"If people consult a tool like GPT, learn something, and verify it to be true and accurate to the best of their ability, they can write a normal answer in their own words."* I think if they do so, they should at least mention where they got the inspiration, but also describe the steps they went through to verify the solution.

Answer (score 9):

ChatGPT is not a real thinking machine when you look at how it answered.

I posted my own answer to [Join twice on same table with different conditions and no PK / FK relations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322823/join-twice-on-same-table-with-different-conditions-and-no-pk-fk-relations/322842#322842) and quickly noticed that the ChatGPT deleted answer did not recommend a covering index.

People just need to realize the StackOverflow users that post questions should look for well thought out answers from those who can actually think inside and outside of the box. [Paul's answer](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3507/877) is spot on, but my post here is just supplementary.

ChatGPT will never be on the same level as StackOverflow, just like Captain Kirk outwitting [The Ultimate Computer (Season 2 Episode 24 of Star Trek TOS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Computer)

Comment: Why the reference to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/)? This is not Stack Overflow(?).