# Add an answer box banner warning against generative AI?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We decided in [Are ChatGPT answers allowed here?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3506/1192) that generative AI answers are not allowed on our site.

There is now an option to add a banner to the answer box informing people of this.

The options are described in [Sites can now request to enable a banner to warn about their policy on AI-generated content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881).

> [image: Example banner]
> *<sub>Example banner</sub>*

### Questions

Do we want this banner, and if so, which option?

> 1. **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Database Administrators. Learn more
> 2. **Reminder**: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on Database Administrators. Learn more

Also:

> Both options have a "Learn more" link, which will point to a per-site help center article, whose contents should also be a part of the community discussion — this article should explain what the site's policy on AI-generated content is ([here's SO's article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy), as an example).

Please note any suggestions for the Help Centre article in your answer.

Comment: Banner version 2 ("_Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools must be cited on Database Administrators._") seems to be in contradiction with the fact that AI answers are completely banned, no? Or am I missing some nuance?

Comment: @Yano_of_Queenscastle I think the intention is to inform people who might not otherwise be familiar with the local meta and policy. Preventing AI answers posted while unaware of the policy will reduce the amount of flags and work moderators have to do currently so you don't see much AI generated content on the site.

Comment: @PaulWhite sure, but if AI answers are banned on this substack, then it seems weird to have banner "_All AI answers must be cited_" (which seems to imply that they are allowed - as long as they are marked as such). But that version of the banner doesn't have a single vote, so it is probably moot point.

Comment: @Yano_of_Queenscastle That option might make sense for other sites in the network, but not here, I agree. But it's not up to me is it. Hence the question, discussion, and voting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are **not allowed on Database Administrators**. Learn more

Comment: I think we could use Stack Overflow's article describing why we don't want AI generated content and the possible repercussions associated with posting an AI generated answer.

Comment: This banner as now been enabled.

Answer (score -3):

2. Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools **must be cited on Database Administrators**. Learn more

Answer (score -6):

No, we don't want the banner. This substack doesn't really have problems with AI spam, so there is no reason to clutter the UI.